# Перевод из числа из 16 сс, записанного строкой , в 10 сс, записанную строкой

Tags: системы-счисления

Собственно, вопрос такой какой и есть в теме.Предположим, в некую функцию передается строка "FFE", эта функция должна вернуть строку "4094". Хочется понять, возможно ли каким-нибудь образом осуществить этот перевод используя только значения, что есть в строке. То есть я не хочу переводить "FFE" в 4094, чтобы потом перевести его в строку. А как-нибудь сразу. Просто дело в том, что данная функция должна быть реализована на ASM, и должна поддерживать 128-битные числа. Поэтому заниматься склейкой числа на стеке, чтобы потом его как-то по волшебному перевести в строку тоже не очень хочется.

Comment: Вам нужна глава 4.4 «Искусства программирования» Кнута. Там как раз рассматриваются реализации на ассемблере (но не на вашем).

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду читать!

Comment: Понятно, что 16-ричная запись легко переводится в 128-бит число (каждый hex символ дает очередные 4 бита, потом дополните нулями влево), а вот вывод в стоку в десятичном виде IMHO требует деления на 10 (с остатком).

Правда в gcc есть 128 бит целые (встроенные типы `__int128` и `unsigned __int128`
).

--

А вот ответ непосредственно на Ваш вопрос я, к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: @avp формально данные условия выполнить несложно, хотя вычислительная эффективность данного решения оставляет желать. hint: переводить не в двоичную (что легко) а в двоично-десятичную системы. (Такие числа были в S/360 и потомках, где каждая десятичная цифра кодировалась 4(упакованный формат) или 8 (распакованный) битами. Смоделировать можно массивом десятичных цифр. Но переводить придётся всё равно число целиком до получения первой цифры результата.

Comment: @alexlz: если идти по принципу последовательного деления на 10, то цифры будут появляться по одной (как при делении в столбик), и для получения следующей результата не нужны все цифры исходного числа. По идее.

Comment: @VladD тут есть маленькое но. @chubakur написал:

    То есть я не хочу переводить "FFE" в 4094, чтобы потом перевести его в строку

Вопрос: что последовательно делить на 10? (То, что выполнять преобразования в двоично-десятичной арифметике менее эффективно, объяснять не нужно).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить ответ, надо научиться делить HEX-числа на 10 = A<sub>16</sub> с остатком.
Для этого нужно иметь таблицы частных [X<sub>16</sub> / A<sub>16</sub>] и остатков X<sub>16</sub> % A<sub>16</sub> для X<sub>16</sub>=[0<sub>16</sub>, 9F<sub>16</sub>],
остальное - конкатенация.
А так алгоритм несложен:

1. FFE<sub>16</sub>/A<sub>16</sub> = 199<sub>16</sub> (4),
2. 199<sub>16</sub>/A<sub>16</sub> = 28<sub>16</sub> (9),
3. 28<sub>16</sub>/A<sub>16</sub> = 4<sub>16</sub> (0),
4. 4<sub>16</sub>/A<sub>16</sub> = 0 (4).

Когда в частном нуль, надо прочитать остатки в обратном порядке и получить `4094`.
Так как мы делили на 10, они будут в пределах от 0 до 9.